# Ejecutar función de agregación COUNT en Laravel

Tags: laravel

buen dia mi duda es quiero mostrar un conteo de estatus 'pendiente' en la vista blade
pero no se donde y como poner el query parecido a mysql
ejemplo

```
SELECT estatus,COUNT(*) FROM `products` where estatus='Pendiente'
```

este es el que llevo pero no se si este bien y donde ponerlo y como mostrarlo en
welcome.blade

```
  DB::table('orden')
    ->where('estatus', '=', 'Pendiente')
    ->orWhere(function($query)
 )
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes auxiliarte de:

- `selectRaw()` para pasar una sentencia SQL [en su estado puro](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)
- Necesitamos agrupar ya que estamos usando funciones de agregación, en este caso sería [agrupar por la columna `estatus`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)
- Podemos tener una sintaxis mas acortada en el método `where` adjuntándole el nombre de la columna y solo pasando como argumento el valor de la condición
- Dale un alias a la columna calculada siempre, de esta forma te será fácil recuperar el valor en tus vistas

Consulta:

```
$consulta = DB::table('products')
               ->selectRaw("count(*) as Total")
               ->select("estatus")
               ->whereStatus("Pendiente")
               ->groupBy("estatus")
               ->get();
```

> Las consultas de *forma regular aunque no exclusiva* van en los controladores pero **no es regla**

Comment: perfecto muy amable 
de casualidad sabes donde la puedo meter para darle el echo $consulta

Comment: asi  {{ $consulta }}

Comment: y el query del count en que controlador lo puedo dejar

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esta consulta,

```
[ SELECT estatus,COUNT(*) FROM `products` where estatus='Pendiente' ]
```

recogería los datos y efectuaría un `sizeof()` sobre la variable que recoge los datos.

```
 $datos=DB::table('orden')
    ->where('estatus', '=', 'Pendiente')
    ->orWhere(function($query)
 )->get()

sizeof($datos); //devolvera la cantidad de registros encontrados con dicha consulta
```

En mi humilde opinión, si solo necesitas contar el número de registros con 'estatus' de 'Pendiente', realizaría la siguiente consulta en laravel, usado la clase modelo de la tabla que extenderá de Model:

```
Product::where('estatus',$request->estatus)->count();
```

Comment: Las funciones de agregación siempre deben agrupar en este caso sería por estatus para el caso de tu primer consulta, además ¿para que conservas la función `orWhere`? Si en la consulta no la ocupas para nada

Comment: Entonces al margen de que creo que tu primer consulta no va a funcionar, en la segunda si estará regresando un conteo pero estará dejando fuera del resultado el valor de la columna status que como notamos en su consulta el OP también desea obtener